# Having trouble accessing ortools on M1 mac

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools

I have macOS Monterey version 12.0.1. I have been having a lot of trouble installing ortools. I followed these instructions:

https://www.devforce.one/14677478/how-to-install-google-or-tools-on-apple-m1-arm64#/google_vignette

However, I am still getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ortools'.

When I did the installation, I was inside the directory which has the file I am trying to run (/Users/hannahamilton/Desktop/local_function). Also, I had activated my virtual environment. Could the issue be that ortools is just installed in the wrong place?
Requirement already satisfied: ortools in /Users/hannahamilton/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (9.3.10497)

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mac M1, building or-tools is supported directly.

Just checkout the master branch

```
git clone -b master https://github.com/google/or-tools.git
```

install xcode, swig, cmake, native arm python

In python, install mypy-grotobuf.

```
python3 -m pip install mypy-protobuf
```

Make sure the associated script is accessible on the PATH (I added `$HOME/Library/python3.10/bin` to the PATH as I use python 3.10)

Then cd into or-tools and type `make python`.

The python wheel package will be in the build_make/python/dist sub-directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where on my computer should I clone or-tools? Should I first navigate to the folder where I have the scripts I am trying to run and then clone it inside this folder?

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how to do this step:
"In python, install mypy-grotobuf. Make sure the associated script is accessible on the PATH."

Comment: Thanks for clarifying those things. After I run "make python", I get this this output: Using /Users/hanna/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages

Finished processing dependencies for ortools==9.4.177


Then when I navigate to my project folder and try running my script, I get this error:

Comment: Original error was: dlopen(/Users/hanna/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/hanna/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so' (no such file)

Comment: Are you familiar with this error?

Comment: Your python is not that arm64 one, from what I see.

Comment: When I try this command: python3 -c "import platform; print(platform.machine())", I see arm64 though

Comment: I finally got ortools installed again. Thank you so much for your help! I had ortools installed before, but it went away after I did some setup on my computer for another project (not sure what exactly caused it to go away).